# Rebase create a new commit when ammending

Tags: git, git-rebase

When I do:

```
git checkout -b branch1
git commit -m "A"
git checkout -b branch2
git commit -m "B"
-- oups did errors when committed in branch1
git checkout branch1
git commit --amend --no-edit
git checkout branch2
git rebase branch1
-- resolve conflicts
git checkout --theirs file
git rebase --continue
```

Now I still see the first commit (A -> A -> B)

What's the right command to use so I don't have that commit.

Comment: add all commits in to a single commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question will be rather long, because you gave us many commands, and there is a lot going on underneath them.

First of all, you started off on some third branch, which I will call `start` for lack of a better name.

```
git checkout start
git checkout -b branch1
git commit -m "A"
git checkout -b branch2
git commit -m "B"
```

These commands left you with `branch1` and `branch2` looking like this:

```
branch1: M <- A
branch2: M <- A <- B
```

Here commit `M` is one (or more) commits coming from the `start` branch which are common ancestors between `branch1` and `branch2`.  Note carefully that since you created `branch2` while you were on `branch1`, `branch2` has the `A` commit from `branch1`.

```
git checkout branch1
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

This leaves with this:

```
branch1: M <- A'
branch2: M <- A <- B
```

Here, I have labelled the `A` commit in `branch1` with an apostrophe to indicate that it is a *different* commit than before because you amended it.

```
git checkout branch2
git rebase branch1

branch1: M <- A'
branch2: M <- A' <- A'' <- B
```

Here, the `A''` commit is actually the *original* `A` commit (before you amended it), and the `A'` commit is the `A` commit *after* you amended it.

You need to decide what you want to do here.  You can squash the two `A` commits into one, you can keep just `A'`, you can keep just `A''`, or you can keep both.  In any case, the tool I would recommend here is `git rebase` in interactive mode.

So instead of doing a normal rebase, you would do this:

```
git checkout branch2
git rebase -i branch1
```

This will bring up a list of commits, and you can choose what you want to do with each one:

```
pick 9361ckv Some earlier commit M from the start branch
pick 62eed47 Amended commit A
pick 39dne92 Original commit A
pick k3nos9s Commit B
```

The keyword `pick` means that each of these commits will be retained.  If you examine the commit list closely, you will see that it is listing, from oldest to newest, the commits which are currently appearing in `branch2` after your original rebase.  This isn't what you want.  Assuming you want to remove the original `A` commit (labelled above as `A''`), then you would *delete* the line containing this commit, leaving you with this list:

```
pick 9361ckv Some earlier commit M from the start branch
pick 62eed47 Amended commit A
pick k3nos9s Commit B
```

Now when you complete the rebase, your branches will look like this:

```
branch1: M <- A'
branch2: M <- A' <- B
```

Here `branch2` only has the amended `A` commit coming from `branch1`.